# How to get selected option ID (with AddRow DataTable)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the selected option ID. In a single row, it works, but if I add new row(s), the function only work on the first row. Why?

```js
$("#hobby").on('change', function () {
  alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable" border=0>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkstruktur[]" checked></td>
    <td>
      <select name="hobby" width="100px" id="hobby" >
        <option id='1' value="Soccer">Soccer</option>
        <option id='2' value="Running">Running</option>
        <option id='3' value="Karate">Karate</option>
        <option id='4' value="Bowling">Bowling</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="chkstruktur[]" checked></td>
    <td>
      <select name="hobby" width="100px" id="hobby" >
        <option id='1' value="Soccer">Soccer</option>
        <option id='2' value="Running">Running</option>
        <option id='3' value="Karate">Karate</option>
        <option id='4' value="Bowling">Bowling</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: IDs should be unique. HTML cannot have duplicate IDs. Instead use classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` in a `html` page has to be unique always. Please change your `id` to `class` attribute with same name and bind event to `class` as `$('.hobby')`. Rest everything's fine.

```js
$(".hobby").on('change', function() {
  alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<table id="dataTable" border=0>
  <tr>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkstruktur[]" checked>
</td>
<td>
  <select name="hobby" width="100px" class="hobby">
    <option id='1' value="Soccer">Soccer</option>
    <option id='2' value="Running">Running</option>
    <option id='3' value="Karate">Karate</option>
    <option id='4' value="Bowling">Bowling</option>
  </select>
</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td>
  <input type="checkbox" name="chkstruktur[]" checked>
</td>
<td>
  <select name="hobby" width="100px" class="hobby">
    <option id='1' value="Soccer">Soccer</option>
    <option id='2' value="Running">Running</option>
    <option id='3' value="Karate">Karate</option>
    <option id='4' value="Bowling">Bowling</option>
  </select>
</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes I see, Thank You,,

Comment: Do mark it as answer if it helped you so that it helps people in future too to find the solution.. :) Happy coding

Comment: Hi, @Guruprasad Rao, I have another problem if I add new function, addRow(dataTable){ ... }. the function only work in 1st row. why?

Comment: That's because you are adding `html` elements dynamically and you need to perform `event delegation`. So handling `change` event  would look like `$(document).on('change', ".hobby",function(){....});`. Read more on `event delegation`